# Screenreader cannot go in items after opening v-select (Vuetify 3)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, accessibility

I used to have no issue with v-select in Vuetify 3. I cannot even go with the screenreader through the examples? Is this a screenreader setting or is the v-select just absolutely not accessible?

Comment: They work fine for me.

Comment: Could you please either provide a link to the component’s demo or—even better—insert a code example to verify? `v-select` is not a primary component listed in the docs. How are you using it? And what do you mean by “go through”? Are you tabbing through? How are you trying to open the listbox?